# Mean and variance of a binomial random variable wrt $n$ when $p$ is a function of $n$

Tags: probability, variance, binomial-distribution

I would appreciate any suggestions regarding the following.

For a constant $c>0$:
$$f(n,p;\,c):=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n-1}{k-1}(p)^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}\cdot\frac{1}{k}-c$$
and let $p^{*}=p^{*}(n;\,c)$ be the unique solution to
the equation $f(n,p^{*};\,c)=0$. (Assume that $c$ is
in the suitable range such that we find a non-trivial $p^{*}\in(0,1)$).

How does $\text{var}(n)=n\cdot p^{*}\left(n\right)\cdot(1-p^{*}(n))$
vary with $n$?

What I have done so far:

First, we may simplify the expression to
$$f(n,p)=\{ 1-(1-p)^{n}\} \cdot\frac{1}{n\cdot p}-c.$$
Treating $n$ as a continuous variable, due to e.g. coupling we have
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(n,p)<0$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p}(n,p)<0$ for all $n$ and $p\in(0,1)$. Then, by the inverse function theorem (IFT) we have
$$\frac{dp^{*}}{dn}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial n}(n,p^{*})}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial p^{*}}(n,p^{*})}<0$$

Then, setting $p:=\frac{\overline{n}}{n}$ into function $f$ we get
the expression
$$f\left(n,\frac{\overline{n}}{n}\right)=\left\{ 1-\left(1-\frac{\overline{n}}{n}\right)^{n}\right\}\cdot\frac{1}{\overline{n}}-c$$
and we may define $\overline{n}^{*}=n\cdot p^{*}$ as the solution to the equation $f\left(n,\frac{\overline{n}^{*}}{n}\right)=0$. Similarly, using the IFT I was able to show that $\overline{n}^{*}\left(n\right)=n\cdot p^{*}\left(n\right)$ decreases with $n$.

However, I am not sure how to understand the dependence of $\text{var}(n)=n\cdot p^{*}(n)\cdot(1-p^{*}(n))$ wrt $n$. Thanks!

Comment: Is there another way to show the dependence of the mean wrt $n$? Also, from the simplification I mentioned we have that the probability $P[N=0]=\left(1-p^{*}\right)^{n}$ is equal to $1-np^{*}\cdot c$ which is increasing $n$. Intuitively, I expect the variance to grow as the extremes grow (i.e. P[N=0] and P[N=n]). Is this true here?

Comment: Thank you. Assume that $c\in\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right)$ so that $p^{*}\in\left(0,1\right)$.

Comment: The condition $cn>1$ is well compatible with $1-c\ll1$. I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: Thank you for trying it out, looking forward to your answer! So far I've tried using a recursion and induction in $n$, and also tried to use Bernoulli's inequality. But no success yet.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}$Define $F(p; c, n) = (1 - p)^n + cnp - 1$ for $0 < p < 1$, $c > 0$, $n > 1$. Note that $\lim\limits_{p → 0+} F(p; c, n) = 0$ and\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial p}(p; c, n) &= -n(1 - p)^{n - 1} + cn,\\
\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial p^2}(p; c, n) &= n(n - 1)(1 - p)^{n - 2} > 0,
\end{align*}
thus $F$ is convex with respect to $p$. Therefore for any $c > 0$ and $n > 1$, the following conditions are equivalent:

1. There exists a unique $p \in (0, 1)$ such that $F(p; c, n) = 0$.
2. $\lim\limits_{p → 1-} F(p; c, n) = cn - 1 > 0$, $\lim\limits_{p → 0+} \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial p}(p; c, n) = (c - 1)n < 0$, i.e. $0 < c < 1$ and $n > \dfrac{1}{c}$.

Now for any $0 < c < 1$ and $n > \dfrac{1}{c}$, denote by $p(c, n)$ the unique solution to $F(p; c, n) = 0$, i.e.$$
F(p(c, n); c, n) \equiv 0.\quad \forall 0 < c < 1,\ n > \frac{1}{c}
$$
[Here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdUMtugzAQvCPxDxa92MQkXqJIVRX3xCf0VjXIGKNYggUZ08ff16lpg7qH0Wr2MaPRHOW7cjTTBDOWJmnSmo5MVHNkT2lCQikJhb5QOFAsgLFINhJiE9F2ROd4lrDe3MoZvzgkQB4q01k0LelGR_SI3uJi_df2_uNqe0OaQj1LMMXj5ssgqdo17FDeqSBGoRjYBXdBNB_OW9XoeLgTpp_Nv3nzO4-4Gv3TiRlU2wzWFcxjMnnQj91PZFM_-mNLKx4owYFxihz2QgAvBeODma_yxS2G3_bqabToZ3kSXH2aue5VExzKTGOVcTVPRvvaKW9H-Qpc7MUpQPnGvgFBqWW1&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) is an interactive graph of $D(c, n) = np(c, n)(1 - p(c, n))$ in Sage. It can be seen from the graph that for $c$ not too close to $1$, $D(c, n)$ is indeed increasing with respect to $n$, but not so for $c$ close to $1$ (*even if* $n$ is restricted to be in $\mathbb{N}_+$).

To be more explicit, considers the cases for $n = 2$ and $n = 3$. Since\begin{align*}
F(p; c, 2) &= (1 - p)^2 + 2cp - 1 = p(p - 2(1 - c)),\\
F(p; c, 3) &= (1 - p)^3 + 3cp - 1 = -p(p^2 - 3p + 3(1 - c)),
\end{align*}
then\begin{align*}
p(c, 2) &= 2(1 - c), & D(c, 2) &= 4(1 - c)(2c - 1),\\
p(c, 3) &= \frac{1}{2} (3 - \sqrt{12c - 3}), & D(c, 3) &= 3\sqrt{12c - 3} - 9c.
\end{align*}
[Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+4%281-x%29%282x-1%29%3D3sqrt%2812x-3%29-9x) shows that$$
D(c, 2) < D(c, 3) \iff \frac{1}{2} < c < 0.82537575\cdots,
$$
which means that $D(c, 2) > D(c, 3)$ for $c$ close enough to $1$.

---

Although $D(c, n)$ is not always increasing with respect to $n$, the following proposition shows that $\lim\limits_{n → ∞} D(c, n)$ exists for any $0 < c < 1$.

> **Proposition:** Define $G(t; a, c) = a\e^{-t} + ct - 1$ for $t > 0$, $a > 0$, $0 < c < 1$. For any $0 < c < 1$, the equation $G(t; 1, c) = 0$ has a unique solution $t^*$, and$$
> \lim_{n → ∞} np(c, n) = t^*.
> $$

*Proof:* Consider a fixed $c_0$ and omits $c_0$ where possible for brevity. Note that\begin{gather*}
\lim_{t → 0+} G(t; 1) = 0,\quad \lim_{t → +∞} G(t; 1) = +∞,\\
\lim_{t → 0+} \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t; 1) = c - 1 < 0,\quad \frac{\partial^2 G}{\partial t^2}(t; 1) = \e^{-t} > 0,
\end{gather*}
thus the convexity of $G(\,·\,; 1)$ implies that there exists a unique $t^*$ such that $G(t^*; 1) = 0$. Moreover, because $G$ is $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $(t^*; 1)$ and$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}(t^*; 1) = c_0 - \e^{-t^*} = \frac{1}{t^*} (1 - \e^{-t^*}) - \e^{-t^*} = \frac{1}{t^* \e^{t^*}} (\e^{t^*} - t^* - 1) ≠ 0,
$$
so the implicit function theorem shows that there exists $δ_a, δ_t > 0$, $I_a = (1 - δ_a, 1 + δ_a)$, $I_t = (t^* - δ_t, t^* + δ_t)$, and $t(a) \in C^1(I_a)$ such that $t(1) = t^*$ and\begin{gather*}
G(t; a) = 0 \iff t = t(a).\quad \forall (t; a) \in I_t × I_a \tag{1}
\end{gather*}

Now, since $F(p(n); n) > c_0 np - 1$, then $p(n) < \dfrac{1}{c_0 n}$ for any $n$, thus $p(n) = O\paren{ \dfrac{1}{n} }$ as $n → ∞$, which implies that$$
\ln(1 - p(n)) = -p(n) + o(p(n)) = -p(n) + o\paren{ \frac{1}{n} }.
$$
Note that\begin{gather*}
0 = F(p(n); n) = \exp(n \ln(1 - p(n))) + c_0 np(n) - 1\\
= a(n) \exp(-s(n)) + c_0 s(n) - 1 = G(s(n); a(n)),
\end{gather*}
where $a(n) = \exp(n \ln(1 - p(n)) + np(n))$, $s(n) = np(n)$. Because$$
a(n) = \exp(o(1)) = 1 + o(1),
$$
so (1) implies that $s(n) = t(a(n))$ for sufficiently large $n$, and$$
\lim_{n → ∞} np(n) = \lim_{n → ∞} t(a(n)) = t(1) = t^*.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much Saad, this is great. Can you prove that e.g. the variance is always monotonic and when $c$ is in a range then it is decreasing in $n$, otherwise it is increasing in $n$? The limit is intuitive due to the convergence of the Binomial to Poisson as indeed p=O(1/n).

Comment: Thanks a lot Saad! What I am asking is: Given a $c\in(1/n, 1)$ prove how the expectation $n*p(n)$ and the variance $n*p(n)*(1-p(n))$ vary with $n$. If it helps you may assume that $n$ is a positive real number (it's an approximation anyways). I have shown that $p(n)$ is weakly decreasing in $n$. You may also assume that $n*p(n) < 1/c$ (this comes from another property of my setting).

Comment: Somehow my function reminded me of the Bernoulli inequality which can be shown via recursion. So, I was trying to prove the monotonicity of the variance via a recursive relationship without success so far.

Comment: Don't worry about the asymptotic behavior wrt $n$. A simpler proof is for that is first showing that p*=O(1/n), which is immediate from the additional inequality I supplied. Then by the convergence of Binomial to Poisson, the expectation and variance converge wrt $n$ to a $λ$ which is given by the asymptotic version of my equation (which is the equation you supplied in your Proposition). What I am interested is determining the monotonicity of the mean and the variance wrt $n$ though. I believe the mean is decreasing in $n$ and the Var is either decreasing or increasing depending on n and c.

Comment: @Avocaddo Well, you claim in the question body that you've proved that the expectation decreases with respect to $n$, so that means it only remains to analyze the variance, no?

Comment: Yeah but I was hoping for a nicer proof if possible. I have no proof of the variance yet though : )

Comment: @Avocaddo Now for the expectation, I have a proof that relies on using IFT to express $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial n}$, which may not be simpler than yours. For the variance, I only managed to prove that $D$ is asymptotically increasing with respect to $n$ iff $c<c^*$ where $c^*=0.6996\cdots$. Will that suffice as a final answer?

Comment: I feel we are close to the truth and you could put some more thought into as there are a couple more days for the bounty deadline. The variance wrt $p$ is unimodal and maximized at 1/2. Hence, for (n, c) pairs such that $p^{*}(n)>=1/2$ the variance is clearly increasing in $n$. Clearly, for any given $c$ the $p^{*}(n)$ vanishes for sufficiently large $n$, and hence the variance is asymptotically increasing in $n$. To complete the proof we are left with the intermediate cases of $(n, c)$ pairs.

Comment: @Avocaddo In order to prove that $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial n}$ is either always positive or has at most one zero, I tried to multiply it by a positive factor in hope that the resulting new function is always decreasing and thus it becomes equivalent to analyze the sign at the limit. No success so far, though :/